# Csrf token in vue component

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5.3, csrf, vuejs2

I have Laravel 5.3 project with Vue.js integrated and I want to use `CSRF-TOKEN` in my form. Form html code is in Vue component file in

`resources / assets / js / bootstrap.js`

I have this:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', MyApp.csrfToken);
    next();
});
```

then I have main vue file `/resources/assets/js/app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('callbackwindow', require('./components/callbackwindow.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: { },
});
```

then in Vue file I need to use `csrf_field`, but I don't know how to get it there, because standard php `csrf_field()` is not rendered inside Vue component and I don't know how to import `MyApp.csrfToken`.

```
<template>
<div class="modal fade" >
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm" name="callback" method="POST" action="/" role="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    ...form code here...
    </form>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {    }
</script>
```

Is it possible to import `MyApp.csrfToken` variable from here into my Vue template file?

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative ways:

1- Get the token from meta tag with `csrf-token` name inside of `<head>`:

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

2- Pass it as a prop to your Vue component:

```
<your-component :csrf-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"></your-component>
```

Comment: In these ways, you don't need to define a global variable and increase the complexity of your code :)

Answer (score 10):

If you have written meta tags for csrf token in the master template then try this.

```
<template>
      <form action = "/user/checkout" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" v-bind:value="csrf">
       ....
      </form>
</template>
```

In the script tag of the component:

```
 <script>
    export default{

        data(){
          return {
            //csrf token
             csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
       }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: I have been frustrated with csrf token, and have tried many ways but yours did the trick for me! thank you sir, you saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

Do this in blade:

```
<Example-component csrf="{{csrf_token()}}"></Example-component>
```

Do this in Vue Component:

```
In form
<input type="hidden" name="_token" v-bind:value="csrf">
In Script
export default {
        props: ['csrf', 'oldName']

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could define you csrf token would be to add the following to your `head` section of your main blade file:

```
<script>
    var MyApp = {
        csrfToken: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    }
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could use import something like the `cookie` library and use the `xsrf` token instead.

with npm:

```
npm install cookie
```

with yarn:

```
yarn add cookie
```

Then in your `bootstrap.js` file:

```
import cookie from "cookie";


Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', cookie.parse(document.cookie)['XSRF-TOKEN']);
    next();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have this all. But I think that I have to add  {!! csrf_field() !!}  in every form. Isn't it?

Comment: You would only have to add it to each form if you're not going to be submitting it with Vue, otherwise it will always automatically added to the request.

Comment: I have my form submitting with vue. Why I dont need to add csrf_field in this case?

Comment: ...because with the above code it's going to be added as a header in every request.

Answer (score 0):

I had same Issue and I solved like this. I'm not very proud because I'm making dirty the global scope

By adding the following:

in app.blade.php

```
<script>
 var Laravel = {
            'csrfToken' : '{{csrf_token()}}'
        };
```

in my whatever component/child component MyComponent.vue:

```
<form method="POST" action="/my/path" class="pull-right">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">       
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Modify" />
</form>


<script>
    export default{
        data() {
            return {
                csrf: "",
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.csrf = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a token then assign it

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            token: '',

        }
    },
 async created() {
        this.token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
}
</script>
```

I was using  Iview so I used it like that

```
:headers="{'x-csrf-token' : token}"
```

But normally you will use

```
v-bind:value="token"
```