# How to submit a form in Laravel Vue component

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

I've created a from within a laravel vue component which I'm trying to submit, but I'm getting a 404 error ThoughtJournalController@store not found.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('ThoughtJournalController@store') }}">
```

How do I correctly submit a form within the vue component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a route in resources/routes/web.php:

```
Route::post( '/submit', 'ThoughtJournalController@store' );
```

Then edit your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit">
```

Comment: I'm getting an error from this:
action="{{ route('storeEntry') }}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.

Comment: Try to type the relative path in your action. Like that: action=„submit/path“. The same path as the first attribute of Route::get()

Comment: Your form is in a *.vue file not in a *.blade.php file right?

Comment: In order to use laravel named routes in your `.vue` components you can use this https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy

Comment: Yes form in a .vue file

Comment: still getting a 404 error with action="submit/thoughtjournal"

Comment: this is the route: Route::post('/thoughtjournal', 'ThoughtJournalController@store')->name('storeEntry');

Comment: Then your action should be action="/thoughtjournal"

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try this

Comment: It seems like you missed the CSRF-Token in your form... This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409893/csrf-token-in-vue-component

Comment: This is already declared in the head section of my page <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">. Does it need to be declared in the form as well?

Comment: Yes, try the first answer of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938284/how-to-pass-laravel-csrf-token-value-to-vue

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to Define the route did you do:

```
    Route::get('posts', 'ThoughtJournalController@store');
```